# known as (a, the) - which article to pick?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, determiners

A quote [from](http://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21582495-computers-will-help-people-understand-brains-better-and-understanding-brains) the Economist:

> Part of this naturalistic approach is that the transistors in his
>   systems often operate in what is known technically as **the**
>   “sub-threshold domain”.

May we use **a** instead of **the** here and if no, why?

Google Books comes up with numerous examples of "known technically as a":

> The sound of h (aitch) at the beginning of words such as have and
>   house and in the middle of words such as ahead and behave is known
>   technically as **a** voiceless glottal fricative.

(2008, R. Allen, "[Pocket Fowler's Modern English Usage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019923258X)")

Are articles in this expression interchangeable? Or do they matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one, use **the**, if there can be more, use **a**

> Part of this naturalistic approach is that the transistors in his systems often operate in what is known technically as the “sub-threshold domain”.

There is only one domain called "sub-threshold", hence ***the** “sub-threshold domain”*

> The sound of h (aitch) at the beginning of words such as have and house and in the middle of words such as ahead and behave is known technically as a voiceless glottal fricative.

since there may be more than one sound that can be "voiceless glottal fricative", we use ***a***.
If for example ONLY the *h* exhibited that behaviour, one could use ***the** voiceless glottal fricative*

UPDATE: Due to a comment, I will concede that "The" can be used when reversing but then it is still referring to a definite:

> The sound of the voiceless glottal fricative h (aitch) may appear at the beginning of words such as have and house and in the middle of words such as ahead and behave.

Comment: Thank you, mplungjan! I should've guessed. But I'd concentrated on thinking whether THE meant that both the author and the reader are cognizant of the term. D'oh.

Comment: Ah. _The one we all know and love_ you mean

Comment: Hah. (0:   Article guides routinely state that the first mention of a term should take "a", and pay little attention to such examples, @mplungjan.

Comment: -1 The second example can be written as *The voiceless glottal fricative is the sound of h (aitch) at the beginning of words such as have and house and in the middle of words such as ahead and behave.* And *the* would still be grammatical even if the sentence is not "reversed." So the difference is not between *one* vs *more than one,* but it is based upon the writer's choice of using a definite generic vs an indefinite generic.

Comment: I disagree. The sound of (h)aitch is an example of a voiceless glottal fricative. But see update.

Answer (score 1):

Use of *a* or *the* affects the sense of what is written accordingly as the reader is asked to think of "sub-threshold domain" of transistor operation as individualized for each part or as unified into one conceptual phenomenon.  An absence of definition implies the author is relying on readers' prior familiarity with it, but [in the article](http://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21582495-computers-will-help-people-understand-brains-better-and-understanding-brains) the author explains the concept (an analogy) in the next sentence.

A [field-effect transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor#Field-effect_transistor_.28FET.29) allows *a/the* drain-source current **I<sub>ds</sub>** to be controlled by *a/the* gate-source voltage **V<sub>gs</sub>**.  When a transistor operates with **V<sub>gs</sub>** below the part's threshold voltage **V<sub>T</sub>**, the drain-source current decreases exponentially with decreasing **V<sub>gs</sub>**, and this is the "sub-threshold domain" of operation.  It is often convenient to think of this as a voltage level below which the transistor is "turned off".

Since the passage appears to discuss all or most transistor operations within a design, using *the* in this context means their domains of operation are unified conceptually.  For discussions of how threshold voltages or operating voltages differ among parts, the author might instead use "*a* sub-threshold domain" to denote a varied part characteristic or application.  A discussion of one single part's specific application could again invoke "*the* sub-threshold domain".